# Globally Detecting Key Presses and Mouse Clicks

Tags: c#, windows, global, keyboard-hook, mouse-hook

I am attempting to create a program to globally detect key presses and mouse clicks. I have googled around and found solutions for both and got them working in the same program. But I would like to combine the two separate classes into one class that does both. I have fiddled around with it for a bit and can't figure out how to do it. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Mouse clicks class:

```
public static class MouseHook
{
    public static event EventHandler imputAction = delegate { };

    public static void Start()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
    }
    public static void stop()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
              GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
      int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            MyGlobals.clickType = 1;
            imputAction(null, new EventArgs());
        }
        if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            MyGlobals.clickType = 2;
            imputAction(null, new EventArgs());
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
      LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
      IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Keyboard class:

```
class InterceptKeys
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static event EventHandler imputAction = delegate { };

    public static void Start()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
    }
    public static void stop()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            MyGlobals.characters = Convert.ToString((Keys)vkCode);
            MyGlobals.clickType = 3;
            imputAction(null, new EventArgs());
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

I am starting these like this:

```
MouseHook.Start();
MouseHook.MouseAction += new EventHandler(Event);
InterceptKeys.Start();
InterceptKeys.MouseAction += new EventHandler(Event)
```

The function receiving both events:

```
private void Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

I am also trying to do scrolling, I got it to detect scrolling by adding these lines. But I can't figure out how to read the scroll direction or value and assign it to a variable.

```
WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,

if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEWHEEL == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            MyGlobals.imputType = 4;
            // Here is where I need to set a variable to the direction or
            // value of scrolling but I cant figure out how
            imputAction(null, new EventArgs());
        }
```

Comment: The [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message says that the wheel delta will be a multiple of `120`.  Assuming `0` is neutral, the direction will be based on the sign of the delta.

Comment: Ah, looks like everything you need to know is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646254%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Check the note on the return value: `A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated forward, away from the user; a negative value indicates that the wheel was rotated backward, toward the user. `

Comment: Ok, so how do I store that variable in code? I tried    `Convert.ToInt16(GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam))` but it gives me an error. I know I'm doing something wrong but i don't know what it is